# How to solve this error message to get access token using Sonos

Tags: api, sonos

I followed the sound experience guideline to set up environment and authorization. When I try to get a new access token, this error keeps popping up. I wasn't sure what it means. I'm following exactly the same step as the guide, This is the error:-

```
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #97.6d06d217.1539357275.34c5f2e
```

Comment: Hi Anni, can you add the link of the tutorial you have been following ?
Also, please add the code you made (the relevant part if you know after which part it starts to not work).
As such it is imposible to solve IMHO, we need more details.

Comment: Sure. this is the [guideline](https://developer.sonos.com/blog/) I was using. The part that stops working is the get new access token. When i request token, the error shows up.

Comment: I wasn't using code actually, I was using exactly the same tool called postman as the tutorial said.

Comment: ok I see. Maybe it is not about code, but about what are the latest instructions you have followed.

Comment: "Now we’re going to click on the big orange “Get New Access Token” button on the right side of the window. Here, we’ll fill in the information required to actually get an access token. Fill in everything, so that it looks like this" and it's the get new access token part

Comment: I'm the author of that blog post. If you're having trouble, you can scroll to the bottom and download a pre-configured postman project. You can then use that to compare with what you have and figure out where you've gone wrong.